# Getting Dropzone.JS to work with Carrierwave and multiple images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, dropzone.js

I'm fairly new to Rails and I've managed to get multiple uploading to work with carrierwave (after about a week). Now I would like to make the uploading process a bit nicer. I'm not sure what's going on but I can't seem to get it working.

My form looks like this:

```
.edit-container
    = simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| 
        .edit-form
            = f.input :title
            = f.input :location, disabled: true
            = f.input :price
            = f.input :description
            = f.input :contact_number, placeholder: "(999) 999-9999"
            = f.label "Category"
            = f.text_field :category_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Category.order(:name).map(&:name)}, placeholder: "Choose a category"
            = f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p|
                = p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[image][]"

            = f.button :submit
%script
    $('#post_location').val("#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}")
```

I've tried doing this:

```
.edit-container
    = simple_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone" } do |f| 
        .edit-form
            = f.input :title
            = f.input :location, disabled: true
            = f.input :price
            = f.input :description
            = f.input :contact_number, placeholder: "(999) 999-9999"
            = f.label "Category"
            = f.text_field :category_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Category.order(:name).map(&:name)}, placeholder: "Choose a category"
            = f.fields_for :post_attachments do |p|
                = p.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "post_attachments[image][]"

            = f.button :submit
%script
    $('#post_location').val("#{request.location.city}, #{request.location.state}")
```

And this is the result (obviously NOT what I want):
[image]

The error message says:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in PostsController#create ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

Could you walk me through implementing dropzone.js to my application?